# texture mapping in cycles for game model

Tags: texturing, uv

Hai following is a texture painted map I created for my character. how can I use image texture for each part of my uv, like cloth texture for cloth and leather texture for bag, without using multiple uv maps.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer my self.
Here is the link to the youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XO9gOeDcgzg

this method will help to consolidate uv's and create one single texture material and it can be used in unity.

hope it helps someone. I asked it my self but no one answered, may be they didn't understand what I meant. anyway....this is what I wanted.....